# Titanium - How to do slide from left transition animation when switch screen?

Tags: ios, animation, appcelerator-titanium

I got a request to implement a slide from left animation when switching screen in an Appcelerator built mobile app.

I'd tried this method mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135606/titanium-how-to-transition-slide-left-right-or-up-down-between-2-windows), but it did not work. I realise that when i call the `.open()` method, no matter what params i put it will first show the view, then only perform the animation, thus render the animation pointless..

The screen is currently opened by the code below:

```
var slideIn = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
            left: 0,
            duration: 500
        });

var view = Alloy.createController("newscreen").getView();

view.open(slideIn);


$.index.close();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the value you set for the "left" attribute before calling the open on "newscreen", the idea is the "left" should  be set to the phone's width and then animating to left = 0

Comment: I'd tried setting it with 320 or -320, both cannot. The screen still show like a normal screen when I call open

Comment: care to add more code to get some help, i cannot seem grasp what s happening.

Comment: Try not closing the index window imediately wait til the 500 ms of the animation finishes

Comment: Tried to not close the index, doesn't work as well